# Uploading video files to cloud in an expo app gives Network Request Failed Error with Android

Tags: typescript, react-native, file-upload, expo, cloudinary

My team and I are working on an expo/react-native app which involves trainee type users recording videos of them performing training modules and mentor type users providing feedback on those videos. Upon submission, I would like to upload the video to a Cloudinary cloud. Whenever I upload the video to the cloud using an iOS device, it seems to work just fine. However, with Android, I observe a TypeError: Network Request Failed situation with larger videos (about 80 seconds or greater). Here is the client side code, which uses the fetch API:

```
export const submitModuleVideo = async (
  userID: string,
  moduleName: string,
  videoURL: string,
  attemptDuration: string,
  reportedDifficulty: "EASY" | "MEDIUM" | "DIFFICULT"
) => {
  const timeSubmitted = Date.now().toString();

  const submissionData = new FormData();

  submissionData.append("file", {
    name: `${userID}_${moduleName.split(" ").join("")}_${timeSubmitted}.mp4`,
    type: "video/mp4",
    uri: videoURL,
  } as any);
  submissionData.append("upload_preset", "<UPLOAD_PRESET>");
  submissionData.append("cloud_name", "<CLOUD_NAME>");

  const cloudinaryVideoUrl = await fetch(
    "http://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<CLOUD_NAME>/video/upload",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
      body: submissionData,
    }
  )
    .then((cloudinaryResponse) => cloudinaryResponse.json())
    .then((cloudinaryData) => cloudinaryData.secure_url)
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

  const response = await fetch(BASE_URL + "/submissions/create", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      userID,
      moduleName,
      videoUrl: cloudinaryVideoUrl,
      timeSubmitted,
      attemptDuration,
      reportedDifficulty,
    }),
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log("Could not submit video!");
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};
```

Here is the component which calls this function:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import AppButton from "../ui/AppButton";
import Colors from "../../constants/colors";
import Fonts from "../../constants/fonts";
import { submitModuleVideo } from "../../util/submission";
import { StackActions, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { postReviewRequest } from "../../util/review-request";
import { createNotification } from "../../util/notification";
import { useAppSelector } from "../../store/redux/hooks";

type ModuleSubmitButtonProps = {
  video: { uri?: string };
  attemptDuration: number;
  difficulty: "EASY" | "MEDIUM" | "DIFFICULT";
  isDisabled: boolean;
};

const ModuleSubmitButton: React.FC<ModuleSubmitButtonProps> = ({
  video,
  attemptDuration,
  difficulty,
  isDisabled,
}) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const userID = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.userID!);
  const userName = useAppSelector((state) => state.user.name!);
  const userMentors = useAppSelector((state) => state.user.mentors!);
  const module = useAppSelector(
    (state) => state.module.activeFundamentalModule!
  );

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const moduleName = module.name;
  const videoURL = video.uri!;

  const submitVideoHandler = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const submissionID = (
        await submitModuleVideo(
          userID,
          moduleName,
          videoURL,
          attemptDuration.toString(),
          difficulty
        )
      ).data.submission.submissionID;

      userMentors.forEach(async (mentor) => {
        await postReviewRequest(submissionID, mentor.userID);
        await createNotification(
          mentor.userID,
          submissionID,
          `A new ${moduleName} submission from ${userName} is awaiting your review. You may access it from your review dashboard. Thank you for your continued support in mentoring our trainees.`
        );
      });

      navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <AppButton
      style={
        isLoading || isDisabled
          ? [styles.submitButton, styles.disableButton]
          : styles.submitButton
      }
      onPress={submitVideoHandler}
      disabled={isLoading || isDisabled}
    >
      <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>
        {isLoading ? "Submitting..." : "Submit"}
      </Text>
    </AppButton>
  );
};

export default ModuleSubmitButton;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  submitButton: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 15,
    margin: 10,
    marginTop: 0,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderColor: Colors.green100,
    backgroundColor: Colors.green100,
  },
  disableButton: {
    borderColor: Colors.primary200,
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary200,
  },
  submitButtonText: {
    fontFamily: Fonts.family.medium,
    fontSize: Fonts.size.size20,
    color: Colors.accent0,
  },
});
```

The console log for the error message is attached with this post.

Other things I have tried:

1. Multer on the backend to get the buffer file which is then uploaded to google cloud storage (NOT cloudinary); this works for any sized video on android, but is extremely slow -> takes about 20 minutes to upload a 3 minute video.
2. Use Firebase and the uploadBytesResumable method after using the fetch API on the local URL to get the blob file. Once again, this results in a network request failed error.
3. I tried using XmlHttpRequest instead of the fetch API, but that also gives the same error; upon printing the status code, it was 0, and there was no responseText.

Once again, these issues are only with Android. Not with iOS.

Another interesting thing I observed: For a short video recorded on android and iOS (both are about 2 seconds long), the bit rate and size of the videos are extremely different.

Android:
bit_rate: 11602168
bytes: 3194077
duration: 2.2024

iOS:
bit_rate: 1296616
bytes: 324154
duration: 2

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The transcript process is a long process in Cloudinary that might take a long time depending on how large is the video and your account limitations.

Usually, the error in the system is 420- RateLimited, you can try using chunked upload, or use the Android SDK (better): https://cloudinary.com/documentation/android_integration

If what I said here didn't help, I suggest opening a new private support ticket: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new